# ng-class content changes but it doesn't apply css changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a page with two tabs and in one of them I have a clickable component that is supposed to change a scope attribute that represents a class. The class content changes is working fine but it is not applying the effect of the class, just when I switch from this tab to another one and come back. Then, when I switch back it applies the CSS class changes.

```
<!-- Element 1 -->
<div ng-class="{ '{{scopeAttibute}}': true }">
 content
</div>

<!-- Element 2 -->
<div ng-click="scopeAttibute=localAttrubute">
 content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it replacing the `ng-class` for `id` and the classes for IDs in my CSS style. Like this:

```
<div id="{{scopeAttibute}}">
 content
</div>

<!-- Element 2 -->
<div ng-click="scopeAttibute=localAttrubute">
 content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set scopeAttribute = true

`<!-- Element 1 -->
<div ng-class="{'scopeAttibute': scopeAttibute == true}">
 content
</div>`